# Не обновляются данные в базе данных SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtf

Пытаюсь обновить информацию о текущем пользователе через форму, но в БД ничего не меняется
(current_user из модуля flaks-login). Код обработчика на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код - текстом..

Answer (score 0):

Перед

```
db_sess.commit()
```

Поставь

```
db_sess.add(current_user)
```

Comment: выдает sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x1bfcb9927f0>' is already attached to session '50' (this is '49')